# Google Sheets Query - Sort By Date; Blanks/Null to the bottom

Tags: date, null, sql-order-by, google-sheets-query

Running into an issue when running a query in Google Sheets. The results of the array formula query are correct but the column utilized to order the results (Col1) is comprised of both blank/null cells and dates. As such, when ordered by this column the blank/null values are listed first before the dates. Is it possible to have the dates ranked first and push the blank/null cells to the bottom?

Ordering by DESC will not work as I would want the earlier dates listed first. Additionally, the blank/null cells cannot be excluded entirely from the results either (e.g. they correspond to tasks without deadlines but must still be listed).

The formula I am currently using is:

=ARRAYFORMULA((QUERY({DATA RANGE},"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 = X OR Col3 = X ORDER BY Col1 LIMIT 10",0))

Seems like there is an easy way to achieve this but I cannot find anything on the topic in other forums. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [SORT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)**

I believe for your example you could make it work like so:

`=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA((QUERY({DATA RANGE},"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 = X OR Col3 = X",0)), 1, 1)` (untested)

If your `LIMIT 10` is important, then I think you could wrap the whole thing in another query and re-add the `LIMIT`.

**Illustrated Example:**

**Range That Needs Querying and Sorting**

[image]

**Formula**

**Simple version defining a range in which the header is omitted:**

`=SORT(QUERY(A2:B7, "select *"), 1, 1)`

**Version that handles headers:**

`={A1:B1;SORT(QUERY(tabname!A2:B7, "select *"), 1, 1)}`

This version creates an array combining the header row and the data rows so it can sort the data rows independently of the header.

**Queried and Sorted Results**

[image]

**Breakdown of Formula Components**

[Array](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) `{[range 1]; [range 2]}`

[SORT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) `SORT([range], [column to sort on], [sort ascending - true/false or 1/0)`

[Query()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) `QUERY([range], "[query]")`